# Installing stackdriver-agent hangs at "Setting up stackdriver-agent (6.1.3-1.buster) ..."

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, apt-get, stackdriver

I am trying to set up monitoring on a GCP instance following these instructions:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quickstart-lamp

The commands to set this up are:

```
curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/add-monitoring-agent-repo.sh
sudo bash add-monitoring-agent-repo.sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install stackdriver-agent
sudo service stackdriver-agent start
curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/add-logging-agent-repo.sh
sudo bash add-logging-agent-repo.sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-fluentd
sudo apt-get install google-fluentd-catch-all-config-structured
sudo service google-fluentd start
```

When I run this the installation hangs at:

Setting up stackdriver-agent (6.1.3-1.buster) ...

Here is the full output up to that point:

```
No changes made.
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                                                                                                             
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease                                                                                                     
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease                                                                                                   
Hit:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                 
Hit:6 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-buster InRelease                                                                     
Hit:7 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-logging-buster-all InRelease
Hit:8 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-packages-archive-keyring-buster InRelease
Hit:9 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-cloud-monitoring-buster-all InRelease
Hit:10 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt google-compute-engine-buster-stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libfl2 libhiredis0.14 libmariadb3 libpython2.7 libyajl2 mariadb-common mysql-common
Suggested packages:
  default-jre libhiredis0.13 libmariadbclient18
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libfl2 libhiredis0.14 libmariadb3 libpython2.7 libyajl2 mariadb-common mysql-common stackdriver-agent
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 110 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2542 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8162 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Selecting previously unselected package libfl2:amd64.
(Reading database ... 71971 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libfl2_2.6.4-6.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfl2:amd64 (2.6.4-6.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhiredis0.14:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../1-libhiredis0.14_0.14.0-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libhiredis0.14:amd64 (0.14.0-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
Preparing to unpack .../2-mysql-common_5.8+1.0.5_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.8+1.0.5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mariadb-common.
Preparing to unpack .../3-mariadb-common_1%3a10.3.27-0+deb10u1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mariadb-common (1:10.3.27-0+deb10u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmariadb3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../4-libmariadb3_1%3a10.3.27-0+deb10u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmariadb3:amd64 (1:10.3.27-0+deb10u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython2.7:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../5-libpython2.7_2.7.16-2+deb10u1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython2.7:amd64 (2.7.16-2+deb10u1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libyajl2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../6-libyajl2_2.1.0-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libyajl2:amd64 (2.1.0-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package stackdriver-agent.
Preparing to unpack .../7-stackdriver-agent_6.1.3-1.buster_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking stackdriver-agent (6.1.3-1.buster) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.8+1.0.5) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Setting up libpython2.7:amd64 (2.7.16-2+deb10u1) ...
Setting up libyajl2:amd64 (2.1.0-3) ...
Setting up mariadb-common (1:10.3.27-0+deb10u1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Setting up libmariadb3:amd64 (1:10.3.27-0+deb10u1) ...
Setting up libfl2:amd64 (2.6.4-6.2) ...
Setting up libhiredis0.14:amd64 (0.14.0-3) ...
Setting up stackdriver-agent (6.1.3-1.buster) ...
```

Some additional notes:

When I first tried to run it had an error that I needed to run:

sudo dpkg --configure -a

The first time I did this, the system hung at:

Setting up anacron

so I looked at this answer:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215708/sudo-dpkg-configure-a-taking-forever

Which suggested uninstalling and reinstalling the offending application, so I removed anacron (using dpkg/apt-get) and then attempted to reinstall it, but it still hung when reinstalling anacron at the step:

Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/anacron.timer → /lib/systemd/system/anacron.timer.

So I removed it again, and was able to run that dpkg configure command.

Now I can't install anacron or stackdriver-agent. Maybe I can't install other things, so this might be a problem with the state of the package manager somehow. I've tried a few different update/fix/repair type commands that don't seem to have had any impact.

The output from uname -a is:

Linux instancename 4.19.0-9-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1 (2020-06-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I have tried installing the Stackdriver agent from the given document and could install the agent successfully.

Since you are facing a hang up while installing the monitoring agent, try restarting the VM instance.

You can also refer the below link for troubleshooting agent installation:
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/monitoring/troubleshooting